# Disable after the ajax success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My ajax script is

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form.tg-form-signup').on('submit',function(form){
            form.preventDefault();
            $.post('Comeon/sm',$('form.tg-form-signup').serialize(),function(data){
                $('div.jsError').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

### my controller is

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_number', 'mobile_number', 'trim|required|exact_length[10]|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            echo '<div class="error">'.validation_errors().'</div>';
        }
        else {
            $mobile_number = $this->input->post('mobile_number');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');
submitting the data to database.....
}
```

my form is

```
<form class="tg-form-signup" action="<?php echo (base_url('Common/smsapi'));?>" method="post">
    <label>Mobile Number: </label><input type="text" name="mobile_number" /><br /><br><br>
    <label>Message: </label><textarea name="message" cols="25" rows="10"></textarea><br /><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Send"><br><br><br>
</form>
```

if any error occured i will get the result in the div jserror.

I want to disable the send button after i am sending the successfull data to the data base

Comment: Use jquery removeAttr

Comment: You can disable the button via JS, but you need to do a check on the server. It's trivial to enable the button again for the user.

Answer (score 0):

In the success handler of your ajax post call add the following code:

```
$('#upload').attr('disabled',true);
```

For better control use the following function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $('form.tg-form-signup').serialize(),
    url: "YOUR POST URL",
    dataType: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        //HERE YOU GET FORM SUBMISSION SUCCESS
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
        //HERE YOU GET FORM SUBMISSION error
    },

});
```